# NoSuchMethodError in Java using XStream

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to save a database into a file using XStream and then open it again later using XStream and deserialize it back into the objects it was in previously. The database consists of an arraylist of tables, which consists of an arraylist of a data class where the data class contains an arraylist of objects. I'm basically trying to create an sql compiler. I'm currently getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError because of the last line in the load method. Here's what I have:

Save Method

```
    public void save(Database DB){
    File file = new File(DB.getName().toUpperCase() + ".xml");

    //Test sample
    DB.createTable("TBL1(character(a));");
    DB.tables.getTable("TBL1").rows.add(new DataList());
    DB.tables.getTable("TBL1").rows.getRow(0).add(10);

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    //Database
    xstream.alias("Database", Database.class);
    //Tables
    xstream.alias("Table", Table.class);
    //Rows
    xstream.alias("Row", DataList.class);
    //Data
    //xstream.alias("Data", Object.class);

    //String xml = xstream.toXML(DB);
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(xstream.toXML(DB));
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

Load Method

```
public void Load(String dbName){
    XStream xstream = new XStream();

    BufferedReader br;
    StringBuffer buff = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dbName + ".xml"));
        buff = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
           buff.append(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    database = (Database)xstream.fromXML(buff.toString());
}
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppDriver.createParser(XppDriver.java:57)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:913)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:904)
at dbt.Load(dbt.java:255)
at dbt.checktypestatement(dbt.java:88)
at dbt.main(dbt.java:45)
```

After changing some of the libraries (Referenced Libraries: xstream, xpp3, and xmlpull) this is the error I get at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Row : Row
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Row
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : Row
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /Database/tables/tables/Table/rows/rows/Row
line number         : 1
class[1]            : RowList
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : Table
class[3]            : TableList
class[4]            : Database
version             : null
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:61)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1058)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1042)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:913)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:904)
at dbt.load(dbt.java:257)
at dbt.checktypestatement(dbt.java:87)
at dbt.main(dbt.java:44)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: Row
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)

...
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you check your application classpaths to see if there are or not multiple versions of `XStream` Jar ?

Comment: TRace?? Is it a compile time or runtime error ? Dude there isnt enough info

Comment: I added the stack trace to the post.

Comment: @BradGermain : I think you have multiple versions/copies of XStream library in your classpath. Are you on eclipse? `ctrl+shit+T` and lookup for `XStream` should tell you how many of them exists

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is one XStream library, but there are others called XStream11NameCoder, XStream11XmlFriendlyMapper, XStreamXmlFriendlyReplacer, XStream12FieldKeySorter, XStreamer, and XStreamException.

Comment: After I changed some of the reference files, I got a new error that I added to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I was able to fix the issue by commenting out the xstream.alias methods in the save method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by commenting out the xstream.alias methods in the save method.